# Capistrano throws: Please install the mysql2 adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I use Capistrano to deploy a Rails 3.2.1 app that uses `mysql2` adapter.

The app is working fine locally on windows, but when i try to deploy to a linux server, Capistrano throws the following error:

```
Please install the mysql2 adapter: gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

Please note that i'm tracking Gemfile.lock on GIT but i noticed this:

```
...
mysql2 (0.3.11-x86-mingw32)
...
```

The lock file locked the version which is fine, but i think it locked the windows version (x86-mingw32) which might not work on linux.

Any one had the same issue? I don't want to untrack Gemfile.lock because it's not recommended.

My `deploy.rb` is like:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
load "deploy/assets"

... configuration here ...
```

*P.S. I also noticed other gems locked with this part "x86-mingw32", like `bcrypt-ruby`*

Comment: in which phase does capistrano throw that error? are you doing a bundler task while deploying?

Comment: I just have `require "bundler/capistrano"` at the top of `deploy.rb`.

Comment: yeah, but is it actually executing ```bundle install```? are there any ignore flags? when is that error happening? do you have a callstack?

Comment: This is what it executes: `bundle install --gemfile /home/app/releases/20121113062232/Gemfile --path /home/app/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test`

Comment: could you please show us your gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about any gems with "mingw32" in your Gemfile.lock. Take a look at your Gemfile. Do you have the following line?

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Given this, did you run `bundle install` at the linux server (or did you put this functionality to your capistrano recipe?)

BTW, if you have any windows-specific gems, and you want to be sure that they are only loaded in this context, use the following condition:

```
platforms :mswin, :mingw do
  # placeholder for gems in a windows environment
end
```

Comment: It's all done by Capistrano, All i had to do is require "bundler/capistrano"

Comment: I have `gem 'mysql2'` and i should manually run `bundle install` because that's something Capistrano should do.